# Could not open input file: bin/magneto error after every command in magent2.3.3

Tags: magento2, reindex, cli, command, bin-magento

I have freshly installed magento 2.3.3 but when i am trying to run indexer or any other command i am getting following errors.

```
Could not open input file: bin/magneto
```

I have tried so many commands and also given access 777 but its not working
i am using Ubuntu 18.40.

Comment: you are running this command on magneto installation root directory ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse i think i am using ubnutu 18.40 and my magento directory is /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento
so command will be same or i have to change anything

Comment: in terminal run pwd to check the path where you are running

Comment: Yes i am in correct folder

Comment: it might be spelling mistake put bin/magento instead of bin/magneto

Comment: Yeah Thanks i did not noticed this thing